# System of differential equations - proof of x(t) = x0*e^{s*t}

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system of differential equations:

$x'=Ax+bu$

We are told that $u(t)=e^{st}$, and we then have to proof that the solution to the equation will be $x(t) = x0*e^{st}$ if and only if the vector $x0 = -(A-sI)^{-1}b$

I could really use a clue to how you do this - because I can't really make any sense out of trying to insert the expression in the equation :)

I tried doing it like this, but I'm not quite sure whether it is right:

$x'=Ax+bu$ => $s*x0*e^{st}=A*x0*e^{st}+b*e^{st}$ =>$s*x0-A*x0=b$ =>$x0(s-A)=b$ => $x0=(s-A)^{-1}b$ =>$x0=-(A-s)^{-1}b$

And I can't really explain where the I comes in :)

Comment: Are you familiar with laplace transforms? Effectively taking the laplace trasform of the vector FODE boils it down to an algebraic problem, because you have a system of FODEs, it becomes a matrix problem. (All things being equal, there are some mean ODEs out there) What exactly do you want to do? Can you give more premise to the problem, etc? Id hate to start typing out a long proof that wouldnt be helpful.

Comment: we haven't heard about those no, so I'm not quite sure whether we will have to use that - the problem doesn't really state anything other than what I wrote, except that det(A-sI) doesn't equal zero. We just been told that we can use the expression x(t)=x0*e^{st}, to solve equations - and now they just want us to show that x(t) only can be a solution if x0 is what is shown :)

Comment: Well then substitute $x(t) = x_0e^{st}$ into the ODE: $ sx_0e^{-st}  = Ax_0e^{st} + be^{st}$, the 'e's 'cancel' and  you solve for the vector $x_0$

Comment: The above leads to: $(sI - A)x_0 = b$, and since the only way we may invert the matrix $(sI-A)$ is if the determinant is non-zero hence $x_0 = (sI - A)^-1b$ Note the $I$ pops up because we are talking in matrices. Your last line would be correct but as you see, $A - s$ is a matrix minus a scalar which doesnt make sense. The I is the 'equivalent of 1 in the world of matrices

Comment: cool, thanks :)